# insert data in beds table when create a room

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have rooms migration

```
Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('floor');
            $table->integer('beds'); //number of beds in each room
            $table->integer('room_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('room_type_id')->references('id'->on('room_types')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
        });
```

and beds migration

```
Schema::create('beds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->default('1');
            $table->decimal('charge');
            $table->boolean('available')->default(1);
            $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps(); 
        });
```

I want when I add new room then in the same time add number of beds according to beds field in room table and give beds name like 1 ,2,3,4 and so on

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Take a look at [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events).

Comment: I have tried but I didn't reached @Wreigh

Comment: migrations are for creating tables not  for data entry

Comment: don't understand what you mean @MahdiYounesi !!

Comment: create tables, set foreign keys in migrations and  in controllers make models with desired details

Comment: I use Eloquent event but doesn't work in Room Modele
 protected $event = [
        'created' => Events\createRoom::class
    ];

Answer (score 0):

I use event listener

```
public function handle(createRoom $event)
    {

        for ($i =1; $i <= $event->room->beds; $i++) 
        {
            $bed = new Bed();
            $bed->name = $i;
            $bed->charge = '100';
            $bed->room_id = $event->room->id;
            $bed->save();
        }
    }
}
```